# How can I import custom styled-components in react

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have `Form.js` file in `styled-ui` folder.

Form.js

```
// input
export const FormControl = styled.input`
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #b2bec3;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 34px;
  font-size: 15px;
  outline: 0;
  width: 100%;
`
```

And I import the Form.js file in styled-ui/index.js like this.

```
import * as Form from './Form'
import * as Section from './Section'

export default {
  ...Form,
  ...Section
}
```

This is my conatiner file where import styled-components

```
import {
  FormControl
} from '@/styled-ui'
```

After then When I use this,

```
<FormControl></FormControl>
```

I got error that `'@/styled-ui' does not contain an export named 'FormControl'.`
However, When I use like this It works well.

```
import styled from '@/styled-ui'
`<styled.FormControl></styled.FormControl>`
```

And I'm using webpack for development and production

```
{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                },
              },
              {
                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                options: {
                  // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                  // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                  ident: 'postcss',
                  plugins: () => [
                    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                    autoprefixer({
                      browsers: [
                        '>1%',
                        'last 4 versions',
                        'Firefox ESR',
                        'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                      ],
                      flexbox: 'no-2009',
                    }),
                  ],
                },
              },
            ],
          },
```

I'm so confused now. please tell me how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import * as Form from './Form'

...

export default {
  ...Form,
  ...Section
}
```

is in your case, the same than writing

```
import * as Form from './Form'

...

export default {
  FormControl: Form.FormControl,
  ...Section
}
```

That's why `<styled.FormControl>` works fine.

What you can probably do in your `index.js` file is something like

```
export * from './Form'
```

Comment: Is it only way to solve this problem? There are many components in my Form.js

Comment: I just edited my answer. I think you can use `export *`

Comment: you mean just export like this? `export * from './Section'
export * from './Form'`  It doesn't work for me.

Comment: sorry, there was typo in my code. your code works well! thanks!